# Flutter: ModalRoute.of(Get.context!) return null

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

My project is using GetX as state manager and navigator manager. Im trying to create a function for  checking current route every 15 second. Here is my code

```
checkRouteTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 15), (timer) async {
  var route = ModalRoute.of(Get.context!);
  if(route!.settings.name == "/first") {
    // Execute Function here !!!
  }
});
```

route is null when i using "Get.context" in ModalRoute.of()

I tried using BuildContext from build, but it always remain first route even i go to another route. Can some one help me with this? or there have some better way to check current route every 15 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one in GetX :

```
Get.currentRoute
```